# Can't seek in this data source

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to load an image as a title screen into a game I am making but I keep getting the error of "Can't seek in this data source," I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I've moved the image into my project folder and it did not seem to help.

```py
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
(width, height) = (1366, 768)

black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (225, 225, 225)
red = (225, 0, 0)

background_color = white

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Battle of the Forgotten Friend')
screen.fill(background_color)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
titlescreen = pygame.image.load('Images/titlescreen.png')


def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        pygame.image.load(titlescreen)
        screen.blit(titlescreen, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(15)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> <Event(17-VideoExpose {})>
>  File "C:/Users/Ian/PycharmProjects/Rpg/Levelandattack.py", line 128, in <module>
>    game_intro()
> <Event(16-VideoResize {'size': (1366, 768), 'w': 1366, 'h': 768})>
>  File "C:/Users/Ian/PycharmProjects/Rpg/Levelandattack.py", line 34, in game_intro
>    pygame.image.load(titlescreen)
> <Event(1-ActiveEvent {'gain': 0, 'state': 1})>
> pygame.error: Can't seek in this data source
> ```

Comment: Do a check first using `import os` then `print(os.path.exists('titlescreen.png'))`. Your image has to be in a path relative to this particular module. If you have say a `src` folder containing code and an `img` folder containing your game assets, then you have to change your path to something like `'../img/titlescreen.png'`.

Comment: first time I see this error message - show full message. If it can't find image then it shows `pygame.error: Couldn't open titlescreen.png` (at least on Linux)

Comment: I tried both of those things absolutelydevastated. The output from the print(os.path.exists('titlescreen.png')) comes out at as true. I am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the line

<s>`pygame.image.load(titlescreen).`</s>

The image is already loaded by

> ```py
> titlescreen = pygame.image.load('Images/titlescreen.png')
> ```

Anyway the parameter to [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) has to be a string, the name an path of the image file. The error is caused  because you passed a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object to the function.